# Check page position in Google search results

Tags: java, google-search

Is there any way to check page position in Google serach (I don't mean browsing, just in one request ). There seems to be a problem with Google SOAP Search API for a long time as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try with **functional testing tools**. Like **selenium** or **[canoo web test](http://webtest.canoo.com/)**.

What you have to do is to loop throw pages (add keywords in google search input box and then simulate clicks on the links to next pages in google search).
And on every page you just have to check if your page title, description or link is on the page.
Only problem is that you can check (its google's limit) only 100 pages (1000 results overall for keyword(s))

Comment: THX, I Know that I can do that by scraping (HtmlUnit), but it is not very fast and You can get a CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered screen scraping? I have recently started using Selenium and Selenium IDE to do Screen scraping of web pages, and I found It was easier than I thought to pick up.

For example, with Selenium IDE, you can click through the links/pages that you want to visit, and it will generate jUnit3/4, C#, and few other languages auto-magically.

There were quite a few projects that I had on the back burner that found a solution after picking it up. [Link to Selenium site](http://seleniumhq.org/)